# "GET http://localhost:8801/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, visual-studio

Google thinks that I am trying to read data from localhost:8801, but I am trying to read that data from another file called "main.js." The error is "GET http://localhost:8801/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" How can I reference the command from main.js without google thinking that it is a subdirectory. Here is my code in index.html:

https://sourceb.in/iuMyon5XI7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to build? How is Google an issue? Is it an extension?

Comment: Right now my goal is to read data from a json file and console.log it into google. Google is just throwing the error instead of visual studio so that is why I said it.

Comment: "console it into Google" makes no sense. Are you trying to use one of their services?

Comment: No, I mean when going to the inspect element on google and finding the console tab. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was doing some more research over the past few weeks and I realized I was coming about this all wrong. Require is a feature specific to node.js, and because chrome does not just automatically have node.js, it does not work. What I was attempting to do was read a JSON file and output it into some HTML so I can view it there. The solution I found is to get express.js and make an API. So something like

`

```
app.get("/api/database", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/DB.json')
})
```

`

And on the HTML side you can add `

```
fetch('/api/database')
        .then(response => response.json())    
        .then(data => {    
            console.log(data.Input1)
            document.querySelector("#debug").innerText = data.Input1
        })
```

`
With

`<div id="debug"></div>`

Right above the script tags.

Thanks to everyone who helped. The video I took the html side of the code can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=293&v=C3dfjyft_m4&feature=emb_title).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reffering to Chrome browser when you say google (it's confusing) but google have nothing to do with the issue you're facing.
anyway I understand you're trying to get json data from local file;
try this

```js
var json = require('./data.json'); //(with your file path)
```